# Mostrar aviso por pantalla externa

Tags: php, print

Estoy haciendo un gestor de turnos de modo que los usuarios lleguen a cierta oficina, soliciten turno, se les imprima el ticketm y esperen a ser llamados "observando" la pantalla de aviso. No tengo ni idea (ni encuentro información al respecto) de qué hacer para que desde PHP se imprima un aviso a una pantalla que no es desde la que estoy ejecutando el programa...¿Alguien me podría ayudar?  muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Dudo que puedas hacer eso en una aplicación web. Lo normal es que tengas que tener dos instancias del navegador web, una en cada pantalla, y dos paginas (una para solicitar turno y otra en la que se vaya viendo a quien le toca). En web no existen "diferentes pantallas"

Comment: Una posibilidad con la que puedes lograrlo, es hacer una web con las dos visualizaciones y después abrir en cada pantalla una visualización. Cada cual puede ser independiente de la otra o puedes hacer que se comuniquen entre ellas refrescando las vistas. Otra opción sería crear dos webs independientes pero que se puedan comunicar entre ellos para obtener el máximo de clientes a la espera.

Comment: Ya que no pones nada de código interpretaré que estamos hablando conceptualmente. Se me ocurre que podrías tener una aplicación que sea la que lanza el mensaje (desde el ordenador de control) y que esta haga una inserción en una **DB** alojada en un servidor Web en la que un campo indique a que pantalla vaya destinado el mensaje. Luego, en la pantalla desde donde quieres que se muestre, tendría que haber una llama **AJAX** que esté preguntando cada X segundos a esa DB si tiene algún mensaje que mostrar y en caso afirmativo mostrarlo. (personalmente tendría conectada a esta pantalla una Raspber

Answer (score 1):

Esto se puede hacer con una aplicación monolítica o con un API y un frontend en máquinas independientes. Lo segundo es más fácil de mantener en el tiempo pero lo primero es más fácil de armar para salir con un prototipo.

Digamos que tu arquitectura más simple es un webserver y una base de datos que contiene una tabla de turnos. Cada vez que se pide un turno se inserta un registro en la BBDD con un ID y un estado "pendiente". Cuando es hora de llamar al turno, se marca con estado "publicado" que refleja que aparece o debe aparecer en la pantalla donde se publica el turno que toca atenter.

La aplicación tiene como mínimo **3 endpoints**:

- `GET /operar_turnos`: **renderiza** un formulario para que el operador pueda llamar al turno siguiente
- `GET /visualizar_turno` **renderiza** una pantalla con el turno actual
- `GET /pedir_turno` **renderiza** una pantalla para pedir un nuevo turno

Digamos además que la pantalla del turno actual aplica una animación via jQuery cuando el turno cambia.

## Para hacerlo en PHP

Bueno, no lo haría en PHP. La lógica de PHP está basada en requests. Entra una petición, pasa toda la lógica que tiene relacionada y opcionalmente imprime algo (originalmente PHP era precisamente para imprimir HTML). Podrías hacerlo? Claro, podrías, si es que el flujo fuera:

- Usuario pide un ticket -> request para creación -> inserta en BBDD
- Operador avanza un turno en la cola -> request modificación -> actualiza en la BBDD el turno más viejo en estado "pendiente"
- Pantalla de turnos está preguntando cada 5 segundos o 1 segundo cuál es el turno más reciente con estado "publicado". -> request de consulta -> lectura en BBDD

Para que esto funcione hay que implementar un **otros tres** endpoints:

- `POST /crear_turno`: recibe la instrucción de insertar un turno con estado "pendiente" en la BBDD, devuelve el ID, está pensado para ser consumido por ajax
- `POST /actualizar_turno`: no imprime nada, sólo recibe la instrucción de actualizar un turno con estado "pendiente" en la BBDD a estado "publicado"
- `GET /turno_actual` devuelve el turno actual,  está pensado para ser consumido por ajax

**En la pantalla que pide un turno:**

```
<button id="crear_turno">Pedir Turno</button>
<script>
  jQuery('#crear_turno').on('click',function() {
     jQuery.ajax({
       url:'/crear_turno'
       type: 'POST'
     }).then(function(turno_creado) {
        // imprimo un ticket con el turno_creado
     });
  });
</script>
```

**En la pantalla que actualiza un turno:**

```
<button id="actualizar_turno">Actualizar Turno</button>
<script>
  jQuery('#actualizar_turno').on('click',function() {
     jQuery.ajax({
       url:'/actualizar_turno'
       type: 'POST'
     });
  });
</script>
```

**En la pantalla que renderiza el turno actual pondrías:**

```
<div id="turno_actual"></div>
<script>
  var turno_en_pantalla;
  function imprimeTurnoActual() {
     jQuery.ajax({
       url:'/turno_actual'
     }).then(function(turno_actual) {
        // necesito comparar con el turno actual y sólo
        // aplico la animación si hubo un cambio
        if(turno_actual !== turno_en_pantalla) { 
          turno_en_pantalla = turno_actual;
          jQuery('#turno_actual')
             .fadeOut(500)
             .text(turno_actual)
             .fadeIn(500);              
        }
     });
  }
  setInterval(imprimeTurnoActual,1000); // cada 1 segundo
</script>
```

Eso puede funcionar, pero tiene una `race condition`. Si dos operadores avanzan el turno a la vez y el intervalo de consulta es muy largo, puede que pase del turno 1 al turno 3 sin mostrar que se está llamando al turno 2. Además es ineficiente. Si preguntas cada 0.1 segundos para mitigar la race condition, estás saturando al webserver y la bbdd. Cada request abre una conexión a la BBDD y por la mera latencia de conexión entre cada capa un intervalo muy corto te llenará las conexiones disponibles. Pensemos además que tienes 5 pantallas mostrando el último turno. Cada una de ellas le pega cada 1 segundo a la base de datos.

## Cómo lo haría?

Levantaría una aplicación en nodejs usando express + socket.io. Usando los 3 endpoints del comienzo tienes la pantalla del operador, la pantalla para pedir un turno y la pantalla del turno actual.

**Pero aquí viene la diferencia**: **no necesitas los 3 endpoints adicionales pensados para operar con ajax**. Las pantallas que renderizan HTML establecen una conexión con el servidor de websockets. Esta conexión es persistente.

Cuando el operador actualiza un turno obtienes el ID del turno más reciente y emites un mensaje a los clientes conectados (para lo que importa, a la pantalla de visualización de turnos). Esta pantalla tiene un listener que dice: "si mi conexión al websocket me manda un mensaje de tipo `nuevo_turno` reviso el payload del mensaje y así conozco el nuevo turno"

Con esta estructura no necesitas los endpoints para crear o actualizar turnos. Puedes hacer las pantallas para pedir o actualizar turnos emitan un evento `pedir_turno` y `actualizar_turno` respectivamente, y dejar que el servidor de websockets escuche ese tipo de mensajes:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('pedir_turno', function () { 
    // ejecutas INSERT INTO turnos (estado, creacion) VALUES ('pendiente', now()); 
    // y obtienes el último ID insertado asignándolo a la variable "turno_creado"
    socket.broadcast.emit('turno_creado', turno_creado);
  });

  socket.on('actualizar_turno', function () { 
    // ejecutas: SELECT id from turnos WHERE estado='pendiente' ORDER BY creacion DESC limit 1; 
    // y obtienes el valor de la variable "turno_actual".
    // ejecutas: UPDATE turnos set estado='publicado' WHERE id=turno_actual
    socket.broadcast.emit('nuevo_turno', turno_actual);
  });

});
```

**En la pantalla que pide un turno:**

```
<button id="crear_turno">Pedir Turno</button>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost/');

  socket.on('turno_creado', function(turno_creado) {
        // imprimo un ticket con el turno_creado
  });

  jQuery('#crear_turno').on('click',function() {
     socket.emit('crear_turno');
  });
</script>
```

**En la pantalla que actualiza un turno:**

```
<button id="actualizar_turno">Actualizar Turno</button>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost/');
  jQuery('#actualizar_turno').on('click',function() {
     socket.emit('actualizar_turno');
  });
</script>
```

**En la pantalla que renderiza el turno actual pondrías:**

```
<div id="turno_actual"></div>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost/');
  socket.on('nuevo_turno', function (turno_actual) {
       // no necesito comparar con el valor actual 
       // porque sólo ocurre cuando hubo un cambio
       jQuery('#turno_actual') 
             .fadeOut(500)
             .text(turno_actual)
             .fadeIn(500); 
  });
</script>
```

Y te ahorras consultar con un intervalo si ha cambiado el turno. Acá da lo mismo si tienes 100 pantallas desplegando el turno más reciente. Todas reciben lo que emite el servidor de websockets y nunca le pegan a la BBDD.

Con esa arquitectura tienes solamente los 3 endpoints que renderizan html y el resto lo manejas puramente con websockets.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma muy sencilla (y un poco tosca) de resolver tu problema, es que tengas una pagina en tu app que sea la de mostrar la info actual de turnos, y que refresques esa llamada cada, por ej, un segundo.

Esto se puede implementar facilmente con html:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="1;URL=http://dominio.com/turnos.php">
```

Con esto, cada segundo se llama a la web http://dominio.com/turnos.php.

Por tanto, tu pagina podria ser algo asi(suponiendo que no utilizas un framework):

`turnos.php`:

```
<html>
<head> 
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="1;URL=http://dominio.com/turnos.php">
</head>
<body>

<h1> TURNOS </h1>
<?php
 $result = array [
    "MESA 1" => "ticket a5",
    "MESA 2" => "ticket b4",
    "MESA 5" => "ticket a3"
 ];

echo "MESA  -->   TICKET<br>"; 
foreach ($result as $mesa => $ticket) {
    echo $mesa. " --> ". $ticket. "<br>";
}
```

Es un ejemplo, en tu caso el array $result tendra que venir de una bbdd, y el formato de html pues lo haces a tu modo...

Lo importante es que en el header este la clausula meta para redirigir a tu web.

Con esto, en la pantalla de los usuarios, que tienen que ver los tickets, abres esa url. Se carga el html y cada 1 segundo se vuelve a cargar ella sola.